# Core Data - relationship goes nil unexpectedly

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am struggling with some bizarre behavior in Core Data. I have a fairly standard set-up, using the CoreDataBook example: I have a RootView which is using a NSFetchedResultsController to display list of Items. Item has a few attributes and relationships to other entities. I have a DetailView which I use to create a new Item, as well as edit an existing Item, which I present modally. In DetailView: viewDidLoad, I create a new managedObjectContext in which I want to make all the changes ... if the user presses Save, I save this context and merge the changes back; otherwise, if the user presses cancel, all those changes just disappear.

The "add new Item" part of this works fine, but when I select the row to bring up the same DetailView which an existing Item, one of the relationships (which shows fine in the RootView in the debugger) suddenly becomes nil when it's presented in the DetailView. Here's the code to display the DetailView in UITableView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
    Item *managedObject = (Item *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    DetailView *childController = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:childController];    

    childController.existingItem = managedObject;

    // ** Item's relationship to Title is not nil at this point
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    // ** Item's relationship Title is now nil

    [childController release];
    [navController release];
```

There's nothing extra-ordinary in the DetailView controller that would cause this. In fact, it doesn't even have a chance to really to any damage ... as soon as it starts, the existingItem.title relationship is already nil. [existingItem is a retained property of DetailView]

Any idea where I should start looking into this? It's been driving me crazy for the past few hours. Here's some code in DetailView viewDidLoad, but the relationship is nil even before it's called:

```
    // Create a new managed object context
    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.addEditContext = addingContext;
    [addingContext release];
    [self.addEditContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[appDelegate managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    if (!self.existingItem) {
        self.existingItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext: self.addEditContext];

    }else{
        self.existingItem = (Item *)[self.addEditContext objectWithID:[self.existingItem  objectID]];
    }
```

The title relationship is set by selecting from some list:

```
self.existingItem.title = selectedTitle;
```

In the save: method, I save the addEditContext and merge changes with the appdelegate context:

```
    NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(addControllerContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object: self.addEditContext];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.addEditContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    [dnc removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.addEditContext];
    self.addEditContext = nil;
```

In addControllerContextDidSave:

```
- (void)addControllerContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification {
    id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    // Merging changes causes the fetched results controller to update its results
    [[appDelegate managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];   
}
```

So the save: stuff works fine for a new Item, but when that Item is set to existingItem and loaded again, the self.existingItem.title is nil. And it's nil from the point where it's presented in the view controller (even though it's not nil before it's presented). So in the main context, it loads the Item and it's title relationship fine, but then title suddenly disappears when it's presented in presentModalViewController:navController.

Really strange. If anyone can shed some light on this, it would be really appreciated.

Update: another thing to mention is that the title is definitely persisted in the persistentStore. Every time I close and reload the app, the RootView shows the title relationship being set. As soon as I select the row, the relationship becomes nil.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is all needlessly complex and redundant. I think the relationship shows as nil because you've got the wrong class assigned to your `self.existingItem` property.

Firstly, there is no reason to create another context just for another view on the same foreground thread. Just pass the existing context to the next view and save yourself the headache of merging to context for no functional reason.

Secondly, this block:

```
}else{
    self.existingItem = (Item *)[self.addEditContext objectWithID:[self.existingItem  objectID]];
}
```

... is completely pointless because you are setting `self.existingItem` to itself. You might as well have written:

```
self.existingItem = self.existingItem;
```

... because object ids are fixed in the persistent store once an object as been saved. If the object hasn't been saved then the ID is temporary and the other context won't be able to find it anyway.

The most likely cause of the problem is with the definition of the `existingItem` property. If you defined it as `id` or `NSManagedObject` then it won't respond to the the `title` selector and will return nil. It would error out but you've cast it as a `Item` so the compiler thinks it will respond to all the messages that an `Item` object would.

Don't use cast unless you know you will be forcing an object to mimic another. Otherwise, you are just creating opportunities to hide errors from the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. existingItem is definitely set as @property(retain,nonatomic) Item *existingItem  so that's not it. The reason I created another context is that I want to let the user make a bunch of changes to the existingItem (or when adding a new one), but there's a cancel button on the page to rollback everything in case the user decides. I felt the simplest way to do this would be to create a separate context, so that the changes don't affect the main thread's context. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I also tried using a NSUndoManager to track and rollback changes, instead of multiple contexts. But it also has the same problem. The 'title' relationship is fine in RootView's didSelectRowAtIndexPath, till the point when it calls  [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES] and then it just disappears from both the RootView and the DetailView. Now with UndoManager, when the edits are cancelled, the title is restored on the view, but it's still not showing up in the DetailView (even though everything's on the same context). Does this suggest anything  I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I added another relationship (1-to-1) which works fine and shows up in the DetailView. The title relationship is many-to-one (from Items to title ... so a title can be associated with multiple items, but each Item has one title).

Comment: You should be either not saving changes or using undo instead of using another context. It introduces complexity and error sources that you don't need. There is nothing in the code you provided that will nil the relationship but your code is "noisy" so you probably do have a some bit of code that assigns a nil to the `title` relationship. The devil will be in the details.

Comment: I ended up using temporary variables all around, and inserting new objects into the context and then deleting them if cancelled. It's actually much messier than what I was trying to do with multiple contexts, but it works reliably at least. Conceptually, I don't understand why using another context is problematic ... isn't it encouraged to create separate contexts to work on different "scratchpads", especially when dealing with multiple threads? So why would this be any different if it's still on the main thread?

Comment: You can use different context but not really as "scratchpads" although I've seen that description used before. The API is designed to use undo management to accomplish what you want. As your models grow larger and more complex, using multiple context will prove increasingly difficult while undo will continue to scale.